# Update arbitrary document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Lets say you have a query selecting a deeply nested sub document:

```
db.mycol.find({"options.options.options._id": "1"});
```

Where the target object contains an array (options) which contains any arbitrary number of objects, who have an array as well (options.options), etc... Since there are multiple possibilities for paths to the deeper level of options arrays, how would one update the one that this find() query clearly can access? _id in this case is a Mongo.ObjectId, i.e. it is unique.

Example json would be:

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Alpha",
    "options": [
        {
            "_id": "2",
            "name": "Bravo",
            "options": [
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "3",
            "name": "Charlie",
            "options": [
                {
                    "_id": "4",
                    "name": "Delta",
                    "options": [
                        ...etc
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case I'm referring to accessing/modifying _id="4" (name: 'delta')

Comment: Can you paste example json please?

Comment: Usually you would use the positional-operator (`$`) to refer to array entries. But unfortunately this operator has a serious limitation: it does not work with nested arrays. So it does not help you in this case.

Comment: @vlad.golubev Updated. I find it incredibly lame that you can select a document based on a nested subdocument, but that you can't update that same subdocument.

Comment: From a 1,000 feet view, I would use aggregation pipelines - specifically $unwrap, $match, and $project.